# Run program during code generation with xtext artifacts (xbase)

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I want to use the generated artifacts from eclipse and run a program with these artifacts.

I am able to do this, but this prorgram is then ran in the environment of my xtext project, not my dsl project. For example if I use println() the console of the parent project is used, instead of in the dsl project. What can I change to be able to use the models (and the parsed AST) to start a seperate Java class?

Sample:

```
class MyDslJvmModelInferrer extends AbstractModelInferrer {
    def dispatch void infer(Game element, IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, boolean isPreIndexingPhase) {
        interpreter = new GameInterpreter(element);
        interpreter.interpret();
    }
```

Comment: so you are asking how to trigger code like this from a running eclipse?

Comment: Yes, instead of generating some additional java code, I want to use the `Game element` that I get in this function to launch my code and display it in the 'child' Eclipse instance, preferably with a console that accepts user input